# Wifi disappeared

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

Wifi disappeared from settings menu and does not give me an IP address.

However:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

will show the interface seems up and running:

```
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       logical name: wlp82s0
       version: 1a
       serial: a8:7e:ea:54:bd:b6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:e6b00000-e6b03fff
```

Also `sudo iwlist wlp82s0 scanning` shows a proper list of the networks nearby.

However, in Ubuntu settings there is no wireless interface shown. Also, in the indicator on the top left corner, wireless options have disappear. The card otherwise won't connect to any network although it scans all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show output of `sudo service NetworkManager status` to see if the service is running? I not running, you can try to restart it with `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Comment: Also please show us: `sudo dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what was the problem. But after spending around 12 hours trying out every and any solution I could find in forums and here and there, this fixed the issue:

```
sudo apt remove --purge network-manager
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Comment: Haha...I just did this and now I don't have a network connection for apt to get the package. Just a heads up for anyone who sees this.

Comment: fixed my issue, dont know how ubundu got network but it installed reinstalled networkmanager and restored wifi

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: ubuntuUssser's suggestion caused me issues but worked (eventually). As per Mike's comment the network-manager is needed for all internet connections, so the apt install part didn't work

```
sudo apt remove --purge network-manager
sudo apt install network-manager
```

If anyone follows these steps and needs to reinstall network-manager then I ran the install command (which fails) but gives you the address for the all the correct dependencies for your os version (the .deb files). For me this was network-manager itself, libnm0 and network-manager-pptp.

I copied these links to another device via bluetooth, downloaded the files, transferred them back to the machine with issues in a directory on their own (so I don't unintentionally install anything else). I then ran the following (before rebooting)

```
sudo dpkg -i /pathtothedebfiles/*.deb
```

NGl, I'm sure someone who knows more about ubuntu can specify a better way to do this but hope this helps someone

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234154)

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the kernel module (driver) has fixed this issue for me a few times.

To do this:

1. Find the driver name.
   In the lshw output, it is in the "configuration" line, after "driver=".
   So in your case it would be `iwlwifi`.
2. Remove the driver: `rmmod iwlwifi`
3. Reload the driver: `modprobe iwlwifi`

Sometimes it takes a few seconds for the wifi to start working again.